# "Empty base optimization" for lambda captures - forbidden by the Standard? Why?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17

I recently came across a situation where I ended up with a large number of nested lambdas to [build asynchronous computation chains](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/zeroalloc_continuations_p0.html).

```
template <typename F>
struct node : F
{
    node(F&& f) : F{std::move(f)}
    {
    }

    template <typename FThen>
    auto then(FThen&& f_then)
    {
        return ::node{[p = std::move(*this), t = std::move(f_then)]()
        {   
        }};
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto f = node{[]{ }}.then([]{ }).then([]{ });
    return sizeof(f);
}
```

All the objects I capture in my the lambdas are *empty*, yet the size of the final object is greater than one: [example on **gcc.godbolt.org**](https://godbolt.org/g/2Y6pES).

If I change the lambda inside `node</* ... */>::then` to a function object with explicit EBO, the size of the final object becomes one.

```
template <typename P, typename T>
struct node_lambda : P, T
{
    node_lambda(P&& p, T&& t) : P{std::move(p)}, T{std::move(t)}
    {
    }

    void operator()()
    {
    }
};
```

```
template <typename FThen>
auto node</* ... */>::then(FThen&& f_then)
{
    return ::node{node_lambda{std::move(*this), std::move(f_then)}};
}
```

[Live example on **gcc.godbolt.org**](https://godbolt.org/g/BmyPMY)

---

I find this really annoying because I'm forced to either:

- Write a lot of boilerplate code that is roughly equivalent to the lambda.
- Pay an additional memory cost due to the fact that something like EBO doesn't apply to lambda captures.

**Is there anything in the Standard that explicitly forces empty lambda captures to take additional space?** If so, why?

Comment: Not really an answer. But I do get the EBO for [*this* code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/144c815691dcb118).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [expr.prim.lambda.capture](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-10.sentence-2):

> For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-static data member is declared in the closure type.

While the lambdas here have no capture:

```
auto f = node{[]{ }}.then([]{ }).then([]{ });
```

and hence have no unnamed non-static data members, and hence are empty, that's not what `then()` actually uses. It uses this:

```
return ::node{[p = std::move(*this), t = std::move(f_then)](){}};
```

*that* lambda captures `t` and `p` by copy, and hence has two unnamed non-static data members. Each `.then()` adds another member variable, even if each one is empty, hence the size of the node keeps going up.

Or in other words, the empty base optimization only applies to bases, and capture for lambdas doesn't create bases, it creates non-static data members.

Comment: Would it be insane to propose having lambdas behave differently from regular classes and apply something like EBO? There isn't any way to publicly access lambdas' members anyway.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Insane is entirely in the eye of the beholder. But definitely seems reasonable to me that if an entity is captured by copy, and is empty, that it should be a base.

Comment: agreed, but that might break existing Standard-compliant code *(e.g. using `is_base_of` on a lambda)*.

Comment: @Vittorio Write a paper? I can review it if you want. Hard to imagine it would meaningfully harm existing code...

Comment: I'd like to do that, working on another paper at the moment though. I appreciate the fact that you're willing to review it - will find you on Slack when I have something acceptable.

Comment: @vittorio Some way of permitting empty member variables with distinct type (and no common bases or prefixes) to share memory might be useful outside of lambdas.  If there was one way to tell a class to be "more compact" that way, then adding a clause permitting lambdas to have that feature might be cleaner than adding that feature just for lambdas...

Comment: A few quick points: 1. *init-capture*s were originally specified as declaring *named* data members (which would be incompatible with EBO) before they were changed to *unnamed* ones; this is partially why init-captures can't be a pack expansion. 2. Per as-if and [expr.prim.lambda.closure]/2, nothing in the standard prevents implementations from optimizing away these empty init-captures by some special mechanism, but doing it now would be an ABI break for existing implementations, so don't hold your breath. 3. Permitting the derivation hack would be a horrible, horrible idea.

Comment: @Barry No, some way to have zero-sized empty subobjects is fine. Mandating or permitting lambdas to derive from a capture is not fine.

Comment: Would (imaginary) lambda derived from capture inherit operators? (e.g. `operator ()`, even in private section)?

Answer (score 4):

The other answers have the cause, so I will not re-iterate. I will just add that I was able to turn your example into an inheritance based one without too much boilerplate. Since you do public inheritance in the OP, I opted to remove the c'tor and go for aggregate initialization.

It only required two deduction guides to make the code almost as pretty as your original scheme:

<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43489af3c28f9f20)</kbd>

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct empty {
    void operator()() {}
};

template <typename P, typename T>
struct node : P, T
{
    template <typename FThen>
    auto then(FThen&& f_then)
    {
        return ::node{std::move(*this), std::forward<FThen>(f_then)};
    }

    void operator()() {
        P::operator()();
        T::operator()();
    }
};

template <typename P>             node(P)    -> node<P, ::empty>;
template <typename P, typename T> node(P, T) -> node<P, T>;

int main()
{
    auto f = node{[]{ }}.then([]{ }).then([]{ });
    std::cout << sizeof(f);
}
```

The EBO was applied, as you can see by following the link.

BTW, since we are are moving `*this`, it may be worth to r-value qualify `node::then`. Just to avoid any nastiness.

Answer (score 4):

Given the as-if rule and [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.lambda.closure#2):

> An implementation may define the closure type differently from what is
>   described below provided this does not alter the observable behavior
>   of the program other than by changing:
>
> - the size and/or alignment of the closure type,
> - whether the closure type is trivially copyable (Clause [class]),
> - whether the closure type is a standard-layout class (Clause [class]), or
> - whether the closure type is a POD class (Clause [class]).

I don't see anything preventing an implementation from using some kind of magic to optimize away the storage for the captured empty variable.

That said, doing so would be an ABI break, so don't hold your breath.

---

Allowing - or requiring - an implementation to make the type of a captured empty variable a *base* of the closure type, on the other hand, would be a horrendously bad idea. Consider:

```
struct X { };
struct Y { };
void meow(X x);                     // #1
void meow(Y y);                     // #2
void meow(std::function<void()> f); // #3

template<class T, class U>
void purr(T t, U u) {
    meow([t = std::move(t), u = std::move(u)] { /* ... */ });
}
```

It would be insane for `purr` to do anything other than call #3, yet if captures can become bases then it can call #1, or #2, or be ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for the quote from the Standard and for an example against "captures as bases". Do you think there is room for a paper that forces lambdas to optimize storage for empty classes *(e.g. "guaranteed empty storage optimization for closures")*, or is it more appropriate to file feature requests against gcc/clang?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Given the ABI breakage and the generally minor benefit, I doubt that you would get what you want with either option.

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, lambdas are specified to capture as member variables not as bases.  So you are out of luck.

What you *could* do is take a page from bind.

Suppose you have a tuple that *does* use empty base optimization.  Then we can write a helper:

```
template<class Sig>
struct lambda_ebo_t;
template<class F, class...Args>
struct lambda_ebo_t<F(Args...)>:
  private std::tuple<Args...>,
  private F
{
  decltype(auto) operator()(){
    return std::apply( (F&)*this, (std::tuple<Args...>&)*this );
  }
  template<class...Ts>
  lambda_ebo_t( F f, Ts&&...ts ):
    std::tuple<Args...>( std::forward<Ts>(ts)... ),
    F( std::move(f) )
  {}
};

template<class F, class...Args>
lambda_ebo_t<F, std::decay_t<Args>...>
lambda_ebo( F f, Args&&...args ) {
  return {std::move(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

That is a bunch of boilerplate, and incomplete (reference capture may not work right even if you use `std::ref`), but it gives us:

```
template <typename FThen>
auto then(FThen&& f_then)
{
    return ::node{lambda_ebo([](auto&& p, auto&& t)
    {   
    }, std::move(*this), std::move(f_then))};
}
```

where we store the data outside the lambda and pass it in as arguments to the lambda.  The storage uses EBO.

No need to write a custom EBO class for each lambda, just a few hoops to jump through when you need a lambda with EBO enabled.

This is one without using the tuple, but it doesn't support fundamantal types like `int` or other things you cannot derive from:

```
template<class Sig>
struct lambda_ebo_t;
template<class F, class...Args>
struct lambda_ebo_t<F(Args...)>:
  private Args...,
//  private std::tuple<Args...>,
  private F
{
  decltype(auto) operator()(){
    //return std::apply( (F&)*this, (std::tuple<Args...>&)*this );
    return ((F&)(*this))((Args&)*this...);
  }
  template<class...Ts>
  lambda_ebo_t( F f, Ts&&...ts ):
    Args(std::forward<Ts>(ts))...,
    F( std::move(f) )
  {}
};

template<class F, class...Args>
lambda_ebo_t<F(std::decay_t<Args>...)>
lambda_ebo( F f, Args&&...args ) {
  return {std::move(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00ee4b1a641ed7b5), with this test code:

```
auto test = lambda_ebo( [](auto&&...args){std::cout << sizeof...(args) << "\n";}, []{} , []{}, []{}, []{}, []{}, []{}, []{}, []{}); //
std::cout << "bytes:" << sizeof(test) << "\n";
std::cout << "args:";
test();
```

`sizeof(test)` is `1`, and it "captures" 8 arguments.

Comment: This is a nice solution. I have not yet tried it out, but couldn't we derive from Args... without using a tuple? Apply could be changed to a fold.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo You cannot derive from `int`.  And I assumed `tuple` already did EBO compression.  If it doesn't, you can write an EBO type that supports an apply-like functionality.  Writing a "good" EBO tuple type is hard, so I punted.  I suppose here a good type isn't needed, as you don't want to store `int`.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Ok, did one without `tuple`, and added a live example.

Answer (score 2):

Empty base optimization works for me in the following case

```
#include <utility>

template <typename F>
class Something : public F {
public:
    Something(F&& f_in) : F{std::move(f_in)} {}
};

int main() {
    auto something = Something{[]{}};
    static_assert(sizeof(decltype(something)) == 1);
}
```

Live example here https://wandbox.org/permlink/J4m4epDUs19kp5CH

My guess is that the reason it's not working in your case is that the lambda you use in the `then()` method is not actually empty, it has member variables - the ones listed in your capture.  So there is no real empty base there.

If you change the last line of your code to just return `node{[]{}}` then it works.  The lambdas used by `.then()` do not materialize as "empty" classes.

Whereas in the explicit struct case, it has no member variables per se, only classes it derives from, hence empty base optimization can work there.

Comment: *"it has member variables"* - Yup, `p` and `t`.

Comment: I understand why I don't get EBO, sorry for the confusion. What I'm asking is if there is any particular reason that lambda captures don't get a treatment *similar* to EBO, as there is no way to access a lambda's data members explicitly and as the `struct`-based solution that uses EBO is significantly more boilerplate-y.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I'm guessing since the compiler is not allowed to remove the capture list (because of possible side effects), it cannot treat the empty lambda as an empty base without any member variables.  I guess it's an optimization that can theoretically work but it's not implemented and the standard probably goes against that optimization (because of the capture) [StoryTeller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45057568/5501675) covers how you can get the effects with lambdas in their answer to great effect.